# Install alongside Windows 10 missing

Tags: dual-boot

I got a new Dell xps15 with Windows 10 and I am trying to install Ubuntu 16 on dual boot.

I am following this guide: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html

This is what I did:

1. Download Ubuntu iso and create the usb pen boot drive
2. Shrink the main C: drive, now I have 229 Gb not allocated
3. Restart and boot from usb.

The problem is that when I arrive to the "Installation type" window, there is not the option "Install along side window" but only this: /dev/sda (see picture below).

[image]

If I click "install" an error occurs: what can I do?

Answer (score 3):

**The easist possibility that the Ubuntu installer thinks there's something wrong with your Windows NTFS file system, and as such doesn't detect that they're a valid install choice for "along side".**

If the NTFS drives are mounting as read-only, its probably because Ubuntu thinks their filesystems are unclean, probably due to hibernation, or a damaged file system. Do this...

**In Windows...**

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

Then retry installing Ubuntu with the "along side" installation choice.

**The other possibility is that your BIOS is set up for your disk as RAID, and the Ubuntu installer won't install to that.**

## Make sure to have a backup of your important Windows files!

You've got a single SSD/HDD set up in RAID mode, and the Ubuntu installer won't recognize your SSD/HDD until you switch your disk setting in the BIOS from RAID to AHCI.

Making that switch comes with some problems though, as Windows will no longer boot. Looking at this article https://samnicholls.net/2016/01/14/how-to-switch-sata-raid-to-ahci-windows-10-xps-13/ will show you how to make the change without having to reinstall Windows. (You can also see http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/).

```
Boot to Windows with your current SATA controller configuration
Open Device Manager
Expand Storage Controllers and identify the Intel SATA RAID Controller
View properties of the identified controller
On the Driver tab, click the Update driver… button
Browse my computer…, Let me pick…
Uncheck Show compatible hardware
Select Microsoft as manufacturer
Select Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller as model3
Accept that Windows cannot confirm that this driver is compatible
Save changes, reboot to BIOS and change RAID SATA Controller to AHCI
Save changes and reboot normally, hopefully to Windows
```

Now you should be able to install Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration.

Comment: New Dells seem to have a RAID setting on, even if one drive. That needs to be changed to AHCI. But Windows need the AHCI driver implemented first for it to keep working. Also other Dell install threads: http://askubuntu.com/questions/884991/ubuntu-16-10-dual-boot-error-grub-efi-amd64-signed-package-failed-to-install & http://askubuntu.com/questions/867488/dell-xps-13-9360-dualboot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1344306_867488 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2345444

Comment: @oldfred I can't get to the last link. Permissions problem.

Comment: What permission issue. Do other threads on ubuntuforums work? I have no issue, but have moderator permissions which may make a difference.

Comment: @oldfred must be the mod privs, 'cause I don't think I have problems elsewhere.

Comment: For some reason in Jail, post said moved to tutorials and title edited to say not tutorial. But moved back to tutorial.