# Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.3 gets stuck at boot on Dell XPS 15 (9560)

Tags: boot, 16.04, dell, ubuntu-gnome, xps

The first things I did was boot into Windows and flash the bios t the latest 1.3.4.

I then made a USB stick with usb-creator-gtk (on my other laptop) and installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.3 with the following partitions replacing the Windows partition:

```
/boot: 2GB
/    : 65GB
/home: 92GB
swap: 16GB (RAM is 16GB)
rest (~340GB) left unused to make an encrypted data partition with gnome-disks.
```

When booting up with the USB the it gets stuck at the Ubuntu Gnome logo. And once I was lucky to be able to install it it also kept getting stuck at the same place.

I turned off secure boot and UEFI. I tried combinations of these as well.

The weird thing is this doesn't happen with Ubuntu Gnome 17 (and Ubuntu server) even though I installed it with UEFI enabled. Also, the grub menu includes entries for the Windows Boot Manager and System Stratup but those weren't included  when I installed 16.04.3

I haven't found anything that answers my question. I think it's a kernel problem because the Ubuntu server I installed (without eth network) has kernel version 4.4.0.

Regarding graphics, the laptop comes with an NVIDIA GTX 1050 card.

Solution (use `nomodeset`) provided in the comments by MichaelBay. Follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu) during both the installation **until** you update the system and install the drivers.

Comment: it could be your graphics driver, provide details about your hardware

Comment: UEFI has NVRAM so it remembers old entries. And the ESP - efi system partition will probably still have the /EFI/Microsoft folder, so grub finds Microsoft boot files (only delete Microsoft folder, not Ubuntu folder). You can use efibootmgr to remove old UEFI entries. Install: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2357321 & Similar 9360: http://askubuntu.com/questions/884991/ubuntu-16-10-dual-boot-error-grub-efi-amd64-signed-package-failed-to-install & http://askubuntu.com/questions/867488/dell-xps-13-9360-dualboot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1344306_867488

Comment: @techvish81 I've added it. It's an NVIDIA GTX 1050

Comment: You need Nvidia proprietary drivers. Open Additional Drivers, select and apply the recommended version. Reboot.

Comment: @MichaelBay I can't install in the first place. The only two I managed to install and present no problems (i.e. don't get stuck) are Ubuntu Desktop 17.04 and the server 16.04

Comment: You need `nomodeset` **until** you install the Nvidia drivers and this means adding it to the "Try Ubuntu" when booting the installer and then also in the new installation, again, **until** you install the drivers and no more after that. You can use this as a guide: https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu

Comment: @MichaelBay I just switched from GPU to CPU in the NVIDIA X Server Settings and rebooted. I got stuck the same as before. I used nomodeset and installed the X.org server then reinstalled NVIDIA (I thought maybe that would revert things back). But the problem persists.

Comment: Update: It is solved by choosing the X.org rebooting and then choosing the Nvidia and rebooting again. Maybe the first time I did that without rebooting in between the two installations.