# Configure network devices on Dell XPS 15 with USB-C adapter?

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, server, xps

I installed Ubuntu server 16.04 (my first server install; facing a [problem installing 16.04 desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945703/ubuntu-gnme-16-04-3-gets-stuck-at-boot-on-dell-xps-15-9560)) on a Dell XPS 15 9560 (2017). The laptop doesn't come with an eth port. I am using the USB-C adapter but it doesn't detect it.

How can I detect/install the appropriate driver so I could get my (Gnome) desktop up and running?

PS: On Ubuntu 17.04 it works fine.

lsusb (arrows indicate entries that appear after connecting the adapter)

```
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. <<<<<<<<
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 05e3:0617 Genesys Logic, Inc. <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub <<<<<<
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0835:2a01 Action Star Enterprise Co., Ltd <<<<
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub <<<<<
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub <<<<<<
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0cf3:e300 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6713 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

ifconfig -a detects it it seems:

```
enxa44cc8c31ceb <<<<<<<<< doesn't show in ifconfig (without -a)
lo
wlp2s0
```

Comment: Please [edit] and post the results of `lsusb` with the adapter connected.

Comment: @MichaelBay done

Comment: https://communities.intel.com/thread/108977

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't think your link answers my question. I don't think I need to recompile as the adapter is detected (see updated question) particularly when I installed Ubuntu desktop 17.04 (it works  out of the box with the desktop)

Comment: If you have the server installation and therefore no Network Manager, does it connect with: `sudo dhclient enxa44cc8c31ceb` ?

Comment: Oh, I see. But what is the problem? `ifconfig` shows the network interface.

Comment: @chili555 yes it connects with `hdclient` and now I can access the network. Thanks. I am installing Gnome
@Pilot6 it appears in "list all" (i.e. it is not connected and can't access the network)

Comment: @chili555 How can I make it work automatically?

Comment: After you install Gnome desktop, it will also install Network Manager and you should be all set. On boot, if the ethernet is connected, it will connect automagically.

Comment: @chili555 that's what just happened. But the HDMI on the adapter shows a black screen. It is detected and can see it in Displays.

Comment: Another question. When I installed the server I opted for an encrypted home. I usually setup the passprhase on the first boot in a Desktop version. I didn't get anything to set it up in this case.

Comment: I suggest that you search for 'encrypted home' and if you don't find the answer, post a new question. I'm sorry but it is outside my knowledge.