# Ubuntu not showing up as an OS on boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb

I have a Dell XPS 13 9434 that I just installed a brand new Samsung 960 Pro NVME M.2 SSD in. I created a Ubuntu 17 USB drive and installed it without any problems.

After the reboot it shows nothing at all and just says that no bootable system has been found.

I followed the tutorial on the sulution of this issue(Since it was the closest one I could find), but quickly ran into the problem of "sda1" not being able to be mounted when I booted into Ubuntu from my USB(Booted without installation).

Im not sure what to do at this point. I've done a BIOS update and I am still not having any luck. I've also tried the other versions of Ubuntu available on their site(16, and 14) with the same results. I've also tried toying around in the bios to see if anything was blocking it from showing, and still couldn't find anything.

Any help is appreciated, thank!

If any details are needed just say and I'll try to provide them with the best of my ability!

Comment: You do not have /dev/sda1, but nvme0n1p1 as first NVMe drive(0n1) and partition 1(p1). Is UEFI set to AHCI, not RAID nor IDE. Often Dell has RAID on. Dell with NVMe needs AHCI & boot option nvme_load=YES
https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln299303/loading-ubuntu-on-systems-using-pcie-m2-drives?lang=en

Comment: I concur with @oldfred. The "sda1" you see is probably your thumbdrive

Comment: @oldfred Yes it is set to AHCI, there are no other options in the BIOS for anything else. 

Any other suggestions? 

- Gennaro

Comment: Some also had to update UEFI firmware from Dell & firmware from Samsung. Often updating UEFI resets any changes you made in UEFI, so redo them. With BIOS all settings were reset, now UEFI does remember some settings. Similar model: http://askubuntu.com/questions/867488/dell-xps-13-9360-dualboot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1344306_867488