# Installation freeze Ubuntu 16.04.3 dual boot along Windows 10 on xps 13 9360

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, system-installation, xps

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04.3 alongside Windows 10 on an xps 13 9360 (with i5-8250U Processor, 256 GB SSD, Intel UHD graphics).

In order to try to do this, I've disabled secure boot and also changed SATA configuration from RAID to AHCI.

When I further moved on to install Ubuntu from a bootable USB, the installer gets stuck at the 'where are you' step. 
To solve this, I went on my grub 2 and when the "try ubuntu..." was highlighted I pressed 'e'. In the configuration that popped up, I typed "nomodeset" before "quiet splash". With this change made when I booted, my installer got stuck anyway at the 'where are you?'.

I really do not know what else I could do, I'm also new at this so I have absolutely no idea what's going wrong. I would really and heartily appreciate any help. Please help me!

This is the 'where are you' step my installer freezes at everytime. (really sorry for the bad image)

[image: screen]

Comment: Have you also updated UEFI from Dell and if SSD firmware for SSD? Many have reported that was required. Dell XPS 13 9360 Dualboot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 AHCI NVMe
http://askubuntu.com/questions/867488/dell-xps-13-9360-dualboot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1344306_867488
 and possible similar models: Dell XPS 13 9560 install without issues
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2357321 & 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_15_9560