# Dual booting Windows 10 with Ubuntu 16.04 (after repartitioning) on Dell XPS 13 9360

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, dell, windows-10

I have a Dell XPS 13 9360 laptop (late 2017 model) (Core i7 8550U, 16GB Ram and 1 TB SSD, BIOS Version 2.1.0, BIOS Mode UEFI). I wish to dual boot it with Ubuntu 16.04.

My hard drive as shown in the Windows File explorer is a 1TB chunk(940 GB to be precise) and I wish to re-partition the drive into multiple drives (with appropriate spaces allocated to them).

What are the exact (working) steps to be followed to  have a successful dual boot system with the above configuration(including driver/software updates and bug fixes)?

I know similar questions have been asked, but they are for different processors and some steps are not very clear (I am a novice and clear working steps  will be much appreciated) and they seem to vary.

Some helpful answers which I referred to before asking the question:

- The user has some problems with windows shutting unexpectedly and
  going blue screen and the steps are for an i5 processor released in 2016. https://askubuntu.com/a/868294/484475
- Answer for Ubuntu 15.04 and not 16.04 (not sure how the steps would vary). The answer was difficult to follow as it had many links. Efforts much appreciated. https://askubuntu.com/a/668085/484475
- No answers. [Installation freeze Ubuntu 16.04.3 dual boot along Windows 10 on xps 13 9360](https://askubuntu.com/q/979355/484475)

Comment: help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall . The install guides are not processor specific. Back up your windows data first

Comment: Ask a more specific question if you have a problem

Comment: Many have reported they needed Dell UEFI updates and SSD firmware updates. You also need to change drives from RAID to AHCI in UEFI settings.  See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/867488/dell-xps-13-9360-dualboot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1344306_867488