# Can't identify partition for installing Ubuntu 16.04 in dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I try to install Ubuntu 16.04 as a dual boot with Windows 10.

Unfortunately the  installer can't identify the partition I set unallocated with the build-in Windows 10 disk manager.
When I come to the installation it directly sends me to **Something else** without giving me the opportunity to choose **Install alongside Windows**.

Searching for this problem I discovered that *fast startup* & *secure boot* must be disabled, but still the same error remains.

[image: no root file system]

I also noticed an additional error I could not interpret when wanting to start the installation:

[image: namespace lookup failure]

I'm using an Dell Inspiron with Windows 10, UEFI and using an SSD.

It would be very nice if you could explain:

- What exactly is the problem?
- How do I troubleshoot this?
- How do I solve this problem?

I'm still a beginner to Ubuntu so thanks a lot for your time!

---------- EDIT ------------
Here are all partitions shown. The dark Part with 30 GB is unallocated. Even through this I still should be able to see the partitions in the "Something else" part. But I can not choose anything in the dropdown "Device for boot loader installation:"
If I click "+" / "-" / "Change" it basically crashes as it doesn't react anymore to clicking on new objects.
[unallocated space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvRHw.png)

Comment: Can you list the existing partitions, or post a screenshot from Windows. As is, the question is unclear. The problem seems to be that the installer doesn't detect any partitions, but that is not the info you've provided.

Comment: Did you change RAID to AHCI? Be sure to add AHCI driver into Windows first. Did you turn off UEFI fast boot, but not turn off Windows fast start up? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions  Many Dells have needed UEFI updates from Dell and SSD firmware updates from SSD vendor. https://askubuntu.com/questions/867488/dell-xps-13-9360-dualboot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1344306_867488