# How can I boot in RAID mode?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, raid

I installed Ubuntu with Windows 10 (dual boot) after setting SATA operation from RAID to AHCI. After this, Ubuntu opens only when AHCI is set and Windows opens only when RAID is set. So, I have to change in the BIOS every time I want to load a different OS.

Is there any way I can run Ubuntu in RAID mode?

P.S: every time I start Ubuntu in RAID mode, it gets stuck at: `initramfs : missing modules`

Comment: Install the AHCI driver into Windows. See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/867488/dell-xps-13-9360-dualboot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1344306_867488

Answer (score 3):

You could easily configure Windows 10 to AHCI using the following procedure:

- First, configure BIOS to RAID, so you'll be able to boot into Windows 10.
- In Windows, run command prompt as admin.
- In the command prompt, run: `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`. This will let you boot into safe mode regardless of SATA setting.
- Reboot, and re-enter the BIOS Setup.
  In the BIOS, change the SATA operation mode back from RAID to AHCI. Save and reboot.
- Log on to Windows again.
- Open command prompt as admin, and run: `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`.
- Reboot once more - Windows should now start in AHCI mode with no issues.

I've used this procedure with several laptops - worked like a charm every time.

In my case, Dell laptop was default configured to RAID, and I had to change it to AHCI for Ubuntu 16.04 live USB to work, since it's not shipped with RAID drivers (and RAID setting doesn't make much sense anyway with one SSD disk setup, but that's another story).

Note that, if accidentaly the BIOS switches back to the RAID default on some occasion (for example, after a BIOS update - unlikely, but happens), and you hit a blue screen when booting into Windows - just switch the BIOS SATA setting back to AHCI, and you're good.

Comment: Isn't there any way to install raid drivers on ubuntu. Theoretically there should be some performance difference between RAID and AHCI mode

Comment: Do you not read the questions?

Comment: This answer does not anser the question