# Setting up a dual boot with Ubuntu alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

After the third unsuccessful attempt at a dual boot setup (running Windows 10 at the moment, want to install Ubuntu alongside it) I'm finally posting my question here.
I completed the steps for a dual boot installation as one normally would:

- disabled fast startup
- created a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu in it
- created a 150GB partition on Windows (unallocated space)
- went into one-time boot option and booted from USB stick
- went into "try ubuntu" and attempted to install from there

All goes well in the installation process until I reach the part in which you choose the partition in which you want to install Ubuntu. The problem is, in that window, not a single partition shows up. It is completely empty.

Thus obviously I can't pick anywhere to install Ubuntu, leading me nowhere.

Thanks in advance for your replies!

(PS: my machine is a Dell XPS 15)

Comment: Dells need a few extra settings. Have you updated UEFI from Dell and changed to AHCI (add Windows AHCI driver first). And most need firmware for SSD updated. Are both fast start up in Windows and fast boot in UEFI off? What model Dell? Does it also have nVidia? Dell XPS 13 9360 Dualboot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 AHCI NVMe
http://askubuntu.com/questions/867488/dell-xps-13-9360-dualboot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1344306_867488
Ubuntu 16 on the DELL XPS15 9550 Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2345444

Comment: UEFI is updated and I have now changed to AHCI. Edit - I am now unable to enter the BIOS by pressing F2 or F12 and Windows is running noticeably slower.

Comment: Did you turn off fast boot in UEFI? That can prevent getting f2 or f12 to work as it boots too fast to have time to press key. Full cold boot, not warm reboot often then does work. Windows should not be slower if you added AHCI drivers, but with fast start up off, is a bit slower booting.

Comment: I do not know if fast boot is off in UEFI. I thought you could only see that in the BIOS. As to entering the BIOS; the time in which the Dell logo shows up is more than enough for me to press F12 a number of times. But again, the issue could be caused by fast boot in UEFI. I'll be away from the PC for a few hours but will check UEFI asap and get back to you. Thank you for the kind replies, much appreciated!

Comment: UEFI is  the new replacement for BIOS. And it has CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode. But many vendors still call it BIOS even if now UEFI. Windows requires vendors to use UEFI for all new Windows systems since Windows 8 relased 5 years ago. Also updating UEFI/BIOS resets UEFI to many default settings. I have to save a list as I change maybe 10 settings, some required, some optional. BIOS always changed all settings, UEFI keeps some in its internal memory.

Comment: Wow! Knowledge injection right there :)
Okay so I found another way to get in the BIOS/UEFI, in Settings. As of now, the settings I messed with are like so:

- Secure boot: enabled
- Fastboot: minimal (the options are minimal, thorough, auto, being minimal the fastest)
- SATA Operation: AHCI (changed from Raid On)

Comment: I've been doing further research and everyone seems to have a "Disabled" option for Fastboot. I am in doubt as to what the equivalent would be in the options given to me.

Again, thank you for taking the time to reply @oldfred

Comment: If you have Windows 10 pre-installed it is UEFI. And it will have fast boot and UEFI Secure boot settings. Some may require you to scroll down on the UEFI page.

Comment: Did what you said, it finally worked. Wow.

Thank you a lot for your help, you just made someone's learning experience a whole lot better!