# Trying to install dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10, but Hard Disk partitions are not displayed during Ubuntu Installation

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

[image: Disk Management]

[image: Rufus Burning Pendrive]

Already Windows is installed. I am trying to install dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 on windows 10. But when I have selected "Install Ubuntu", Ubuntu is loading in Pen drive but not in Hard Disk. I am getting message "You need at least 8.6 GB disk space to install Ubuntu". How to install Ubuntu in Hard disk but not in pen drive. Attaching Images of Disk Management and Rufus Pen drive burning.

Thank you.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.8 GiB, 1905045504 bytes, 3720792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 91 MiB, 95408128 bytes, 186344 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 34.6 MiB, 36216832 bytes, 70736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 140.7 MiB, 147496960 bytes, 288080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 2.3 MiB, 2355200 bytes, 4600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 14.5 MiB, 15208448 bytes, 29704 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 3.7 MiB, 3878912 bytes, 7576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 14.6 GiB, 15664676864 bytes, 30595072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E181D703-173C-40A9-865A-301358A91832

Device     Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 30595038 30592991 14.6G Microsoft basic data
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.8 GiB, 1905045504 bytes, 3720792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 91 MiB, 95408128 bytes, 186344 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 34.6 MiB, 36216832 bytes, 70736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 140.7 MiB, 147496960 bytes, 288080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 2.3 MiB, 2355200 bytes, 4600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 14.5 MiB, 15208448 bytes, 29704 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 3.7 MiB, 3878912 bytes, 7576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 14.6 GiB, 15664676864 bytes, 30595072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E181D703-173C-40A9-865A-301358A91832

Device     Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 30595038 30592991 14.6G Microsoft basic data
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Are you trying to install on Disk 0 or Disk 1?

Comment: You have to select the appropriate disk for installation

Comment: I am trying to install on disk 0 with 751.95 GB Unallocated

Comment: drive.google.com/file/d/1R4pVtR2-47HTiJrmErRnWud9gVBeX746/… This link shows that during installation of Ubuntu Hard disk partitions are not visible

Comment: https://www.dell.com/support/article/de-de/sln301754/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-windows-8-or-10-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en
Solved the issue
I was using Dell XPS. Dell has given detailed step by step guidence to install dual boot with widows.

Answer (score 0):

To get Dual boot working fine on your Dell laptop, follow these steps:

**Section - I: Getting Windows OS ready for Dual-boot**

- Login to your `Windows` machine with an Administrative account and right-click on the **Start Menu >> Command Prompt (Admin)** option to open Windows Command Line with elevated privileges
- Once you are in the command prompt, type `diskmgmt.msc` to open "Disk Management Utility". From here, right click on the "C:" partition and select **Shrink Volume** in order to resize the partition
- On "Shrink C:" enter a value to shrink in MB and hit the **Shrink** option to start partition resize

**Note:** Do not forget to create a Bootable USB having Ubuntu loaded into it before you start with the next section.

**Section - II: Installing Ubuntu OS**

- Reboot the machine and instruct the BIOS/UEFI to boot-up from the DVD/USB by pressing a special function key (usually its <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> depending on the vendor specifications)
- Once the media boot-up, a new Grub screen should appear on your monitor. From the menu select **Install Ubuntu** and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to continue

**Note:** After the boot media finishes loading into RAM you will end up with a completely functional `Ubuntu` system running in live mode

- On the "Launcher" hit on the second icon from the top, **Install Ubuntu 18.04**, and the installer utility will start. Choose the language you wish to perform the installation and click on the **Continue** button to proceed further
- Next, leave both options from **Preparing to Install Ubuntu** unchecked and hit on the **Continue** button again
- On the "Installation Type" screen, prefer to choose the **Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager** option if you want to automate the process and do not wish to have a personalized partition scheme. In case you want a custom partition layout, check the **Something Else** option and hit on the "Continue" button to proceed further.

**P.S.:** The option "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" should be avoided on dual-boot because is potentially dangerous and will wipe out your disk completely.

If you aren't able to see any partitions here, then it means an error in the partition table. `Windows` often ignores these errors and seem to work normally, but `Ubuntu` doesn't ignore them and doesn't show partitions.
I would recommend you to Boot into live mode first, and check the partitions with the following command:
`sudo fdisk -l` (small L)

Post the output here and we'll see if it finds something.

However, if your partitions are displayed properly, then you can proceed with the installation:

- Now, if you go with "Something Else" option, its time to create the partitions manually. I would recommend that you create three partitions, one for **root**,  one for the **Home** and one "Swap" partition.
  To create the first **root** partition, select the free space (the shrinking space from Windows created earlier) and hit on the "+" icon below. On partition settings use the following configurations and hit OK to apply changes:

> Size = at least 20000 MB
>
> Type for the new partition = Primary
>
> Location for the new partition = Beginning
>
> Use as = EXT4 journaling file system
>
> Mount point = /

- Similarly, create the "Home" partition and the "Swap" partition. For "Home" use the following configuration:

> Size = all remaining free space
>
> Type for the new partition = Primary
>
> Location for the new partition = Beginning
>
> Use as = EXT4 journaling file system
>
> Mount point = /home

- When you are finished creating all partitions as per your requirements, hit the **Install Now** button in order to apply the changes to disk and start with the installation process. A pop-up window might appear to inform you about the "Swap" space, but you can ignore the alert by pressing on the "Continue" button
- Next a new pop-up window will ask you if you agree with committing changes to disk. Hit the **Continue** button to write changes to disk and the installation process will now start

Once you are done installing `Ubuntu` OS, proceed with the next section.

**Section - III: Setting Up the GRUB Menu**

- Boot into your `Windows` OS
- Combine the keys <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> together and type **cmd** to open command prompt.
- Type the command: `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

**P.S.** - You do not need to have admin rights on command prompt before you perform the above action.

If you wish to switch between the OS, just reboot the computer and select your preferred OS from the Grub menu.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R4pVtR2-47HTiJrmErRnWud9gVBeX746/view?usp=sharing  This link shows that during installation of Ubuntu Hard disk partitions are not visible

Comment: I need the authorization to access this file.

Comment: given  authorization to access this file

Comment: Check out my answer. I have shared this command: `sudo fdisk -l` (small L)

Edit your question and post the output of this command and we'll see if it finds something.

Comment: output of "sudo fdisk -l"  is pasted in question. I am getting the out put of the command when i login with "Test Ubantu Installtion" option during starting of system

Comment: Can you try making your USB bootable using the "Universal USB Installer" software instead of Rufus? UUI never gave me any such errors. So, just want to be sure once. 
Just want to check if this is happening due to corrupt partitions or because of a faulty .iso OS image.

Comment: I am able to boot in windows successfully, I am still in a stage of installing ubuntu with USB Drive. I am able to login ubuntu with "try ubuntu without installing" then i gave the output of sudo fdisk -l

Comment: You are already having 750GB Unallocated space on your disk. We will use this space to install Ubuntu. Just do the following: 

1. Install "Universal USB Installer" on your Windows OS. 
2. Take a 16GB pen-drive (or more) and format it completely (FAT). 
3. Insert your pen-drive, start the UUI software. Let it detect your USB. Once done, select your Ubuntu .iso file and let the tool convert it into a bootable USB.
4. Once done, reboot your system, and follow my answer stepwise to install Ubuntu. 

Hopefully, you should see your partitions now. Do Update me on the status.

Comment: Installed Universal USB Installer and made USB bootable. Again I am unable to see Harddisk Partitions in Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Its a brand new Dell XPS i7 16 GB laptop. I am trying to install Ubantu along with Windows 10. I am planning to install in 751 GB un-allocated space.

Comment: See, even I possess a Dell laptop and I was able to dual-boot it. What confuses me is: why is your partition table hidden? I can ask you to take a BACKUP of your Windows partitions, next clean format your hard disk completely erasing Windows OS. Re-install Windows again followed by Ubuntu. But unsure if this whole process will be worth it?

Answer (score 0):

[Dell XPS 13 9360 Dualboot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867488/dell-xps-13-9360-dualboot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-16-04)
Gave answer 
Now I am able to see Hard drive partitions while installing Ubuntu.

Change Sata Operation to AHCI: BIOS->Settings->System Configuration->SATA Operation->AHCI.
By changing this AHCI option windows got corrupted and I have to reinstall Windows again.