# Dual Boot Ubuntu and Windows on XPS 15 9500 with multiple hard drives

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, raid, ahci

I have the dell xps 15 9500 with windows currently installed on the 256gb ssd that comes with the laptop.

The laptop has 2 ssd slots. Thus, I want to add a terabyte ssd to the 2nd slot.

I wanted to dual boot with ubuntu. The current storage settings for the hard disk with windows is RAID.

I am a noob to this whole dual boot process and had some questions about how to do it

What would be the recommended configuration for dual booting both OS here?

1. Should I add the ubuntu to the 1tb hard drive or partition the 256 and add it to that?
2. Either way (adding ubuntu to the 256 or the 1tb), is it possible to have a shared partition between the windows and the ubuntu?
3. What should the different drives be configured to: RAID vs AHCI?
4. basically what is the best way to set it up so that I have a good experience booting up and sharing content between the two OS?

thanks for the help

Comment: Dell typically needs UEFI update & SSD firmware update (even if new). https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=enWindows AHCI driver install: 
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/867488/dell-xps-13-9360-dualboot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1344306_867488

Answer (score 0):

### Dual Boot Ubuntu and Windows

1. Unplug the Windows SSD and install Ubuntu on it's own SSD. Make sure to install in the same BIOS/UEFI mode Windows was installed in.
2. Windows and Ubuntu can share NTFS and FAT32 partitions. Because of the SSD size go with NTFS. With Windows, FAT32 partitions are limited in size.
3. I prefer AHCI other users prefer RAID.
4. After setting up Ubuntu, plug in the Windows SSD, boot the Ubuntu SSD and run `sudo update-grub` to put Windows on the grub boot menu. Use Disks to select mount options for the shared partitions if necessary.

Comment: Can the different SSDs have different settings? Like can one have RAID and the other AHCI and both still share the other partitions?

Comment: @Mukund I have never tried that, It is beyond the scope of my answer.